# New kernel broke the USB cameras on Ubuntu Desktop 16.04

Tags: 16.04, usb, kernel, webcam, camera

The new kernel versions (4.4.0-186-generic and 4.4.0-187-generic) the ubuntu cannot recognizes my USB cameras (neither the original from the laptop or another USB webcam). If I start on the previous kernel version (4.4.0-185-generic), both work fine.

Here is the result of "lsusb":
...

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b537 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 046d:0892 Logitech, Inc. OrbiCam
```

...

But they do not appear as /dev/video0 and /dev/video1, and cannot be detected by cheese, or zoom, or meet, and etc.

Is there any additional driver required for those kernel versions, or it is really broken?

Thank you

Comment: you are two versions behind the current one. Maybe you should try to run Ubuntu 20.04 as a live stick and check if your cam is supported. 16.04 will be EOL in less than 6 months...

Comment: I am using some software (development platforms) that is only available for 16.04, so I will need to stick to it for a while yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the librealsense, that perform a patch on the uvc driver at installation. I just uninstalled the realsense packages, and it started working immediately.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem! Unfortunately I cannot uninstall realsense because I use it.. do you have any reference for this issue so I can check ? Or any idea ?

Comment: I am not using realsense at this moment, but maybe they corrected it, and removing and installing again may work.. Have you tried?

Comment: Thank you, I tried with no luck.. I then opened an issue on their github.. let's see what happen! :)